# Mongoose query.populate only returns objectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When trying to populate one field all that is returned is the objectid that was originally saved for that field

In `models/gifts.js`

```
var GiftSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        owner: {
            user: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User',
                required: false
            },
            nonRegisteredEmail: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
            nonRegisteredName: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            }
        },
        description: String,
        url: String
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Gift', GiftSchema);
```

In `models/user.js`

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
  },
  hashedPassword: String,
  provider: String,
  salt: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I save my `gift` models by adding the `_id` for the user to the `owner.user` field in my `gift`.

Then when I try to populate the `user` field during a query only the `_id` field is returned. EX `5388bb3a82f0e4003100a6ba`

```
exports.getAll = function (req, res) {
        return Gift.find()
            .populate({
                path:'user',
                model:'User'
            })
            .exec(function(err,gifts){
                if(!err)
                {
                    return res.json(gifts);
                }
                else{
                    return res.send(err);
                }
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path you want to populate is `owner.user`, not just `user`, so you should change this:

```
return Gift.find()
    .populate({
        path:'user',
        model:'User'
    })
```

To this:

```
return Gift.find()
    .populate({
        path:'owner.user',
        model:'User'
    })
```